# Error validating field `category` in model `Product`

Tags: typescript, database-schema, prisma, prisma2

[Prisma Models Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dykZC.png)Im new in this stackoverflow,

please Help me, I have a problem with Data Modeling in Prisma like this
and error like this :

"Error validating field `category` in model `Product`: The relation field `category` on model `Product` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `Category`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually."
.

please answer this immediately
Thank Youuu

I hope The Models data can be Migrate as well...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that you are missing a relation field on the `Category` model that references the Product model `category`field.

You would need to add a product field in Category model as shown below

```js
model Category {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  user   User? @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  userId  String
  products Product[] // This creates a relationship between Category and Product
}
```

This is documented [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations)